# erlang: split or filter list by element position

Tags: list, erlang

What is the most correct (and fastest) way in Erlang to split the given list into sublists depending on the element position? E.g. I want to get the sublist of every Nth elements from list: [1,2,3,14,5,16,7,8]   to   [1,14,7], [2,5,8], [3,16]? The N could have any reasonable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the *fastest* way? Every time I start implementation with easiest (most naive) way. And only when I realize that it is performance bottleneck, I start optimize it.

So, most naive way:

```
split(List, ByElem) ->
  do_split(List, lists:duplicate(ByElem, []), []).

do_split([], RestGroups, Acc) ->
  Groups = lists:reverse(Acc) ++ RestGroups,
  [ lists:reverse(G) || G <- Groups ];

do_split([Elem | Rest], [Group | RestGroups], Acc) ->
  do_split(Rest, RestGroups, [[Elem | Group] | Acc]);

do_split(List, [], Acc) ->
  do_split(List, lists:reverse(Acc), []).
```

Actually, I believe there is nothing to do with performance of this code, and I don't see any ways to dramatically improve it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to filter on position in a list, so you have to use split:

```
1> Sp = fun Sp(L,N,R) when length(L) =< N -> lists:reverse([L|R]);          
1> Sp(L,N,R) -> {L1,L2} = lists:split(N,L), Sp(L2,N,[L1|R]) end.            
#Fun<erl_eval.42.90072148>
2> Split= fun (L,N) when is_list(L), is_integer(N), N > 0 -> Sp(L,N,[]) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.90072148>
3> Split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3).                                              
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
4>
```

**[edit]** Ooops, it doesn't answer the question. If you don't mind the order of sublist, another solution maybe

```
1> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
2> N = 3.
3
3> [lists:reverse(Y) || Y <- lists:foldl(fun(X,[H|T]) -> T++[[X|H]] end , lists:duplicate(N,[]),L)].               
[[3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8]]
4>
```

the next version restore the order:

```
1> F = fun(List,Chunk) -> {Si,L1} = lists:foldl(fun(X,{S,[H|T]}) -> {S+1,T++[[X|H]]} end , {0,lists:duplicate(Chunk,[])},List),
1> {L2,L3} = lists:split(Chunk - Si rem Chunk,L1),                              
1> [lists:reverse(Y) || Y <- L3 ++ L2] end.                                     
#Fun<erl_eval.12.90072148>
2> F(lists:seq(1,130),11).    
[[1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,100,111,122],
 [2,13,24,35,46,57,68,79,90,101,112,123],
 [3,14,25,36,47,58,69,80,91,102,113,124],
 [4,15,26,37,48,59,70,81,92,103,114,125],
 [5,16,27,38,49,60,71,82,93,104,115,126],
 [6,17,28,39,50,61,72,83,94,105,116,127],
 [7,18,29,40,51,62,73,84,95,106,117,128],
 [8,19,30,41,52,63,74,85,96,107,118,129],
 [9,20,31,42,53,64,75,86,97,108,119,130],
 [10,21,32,43,54,65,76,87,98,109,120],
 [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,110,121]]
3>
```

Comment: I know how to simply split list, but here I need to create a lists of Nth elements. I.e. every 3rd element lists:

3> Split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],3).                                              
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6]]

Comment: @Darkkey, I put a version that answer to your initial question.